# How often does New York subways get cancelled by cold weather?

Tags: usa, public-transport, new-york-city

I'm going to NY on the first fortnight of February. I'm aware that subways are the main means of transportation but I'm worried about frosts/freezes that could interrupt the service.
Does it happen frequently enough to consider it? If so, Which other means of transportation are recommended?

Extra information:

- I will be staying in Manhattan, near Time Square or Central Park (haven't decided yet).
- Another 3 persons are traveling with me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

New York City subway service has only been [interrupted once for snow in 110 years](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/01/28/upshot/shutting-down-new-yorks-subways-is-very-expensive.html?_r=0), and the decision to do so was criticized when the snowstorm actually dropped far less snow than expected.

It was also [interrupted for Hurricane Sandy](http://science.time.com/2012/10/30/the-lessons-from-new-yorks-flooded-subways/), back in 2012, but that was actually a well-advised closure.

You're extremely unlikely to see a system-wide service interruption, but individual services may be delayed or cancelled due to accidents, mechanical problems or the like. You can get information on service advisories from the [MTA website](http://alert.mta.info/) or [Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/nyctsubway), or by [email or SMS](https://www.mymtaalerts.com/).